# Convert 2D into 3D using reshape subject to conditions

Tags: matlab

I want to use reshape.

```
 v=[1:20 ;2:2:40 ;3:3:60 ;4:4:80];
```

Using reshape(v,4,4,5) gives output:

```
ans(:,:,1) =   
 1     5     9    13
 2     6    10    14
 3     7    11    15
 4     8    12    16

ans(:,:,2) =

17     2    10    18
18     4    12    20
19     6    14    22
20     8    16    24
```

And so on. But I desire

```
ans(:,:,1)=

 1     2     3     4
 2     4     6     8
 3     6     9    12
 4     8    12    16

ans(:,:,2)=
 5    10    15    20
 6    12    18    24
 7    14    21    28
 8    16    24    32
```

reshape(v',4,4,5) didn't work for me either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function. You just need to transpose your 3D slices using [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html). i.e.

```
permute(reshape(v,4,4,[]),[2 1 3])
```